# Use Python to Check for a colour of a pixel at a certain Coordinate

Tags: python, colors, screenshot

I am  trying to make a progam for a game that will run in the background as like a 'checker'.
My idea is that it will constantly take screenshots and if I die in the game, a certain pixel at a coordinate on screen that I have chosen will turn a certain colour, which the program should recognise and then run a different command when I die.

```
while u > v:
      myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
      myScreenshot.save(DIRECTORY)
      image = Image.open(DIRECTORY)
      picture = image.load()
      print(picture[1302, 341])
      n = n+1
      v += 1
```

I have also tried this:

```
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
a = 10
b = 1
time.sleep(2)
while a > b:
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    x_coord = 1302
    y_coord = 341
    color_at_coord = str(screenshot.getpixel((x_coord, y_coord)))
    print(color_at_coord)
    b +=1
    if color_at_coord == "(254, 252, 0)":
        print("Correct!")
```

However, neither have really worked, I can get the program to take screenshots, but for some reason when I die in the game, the program notices a change in colour (it prints a different colour code than when I am alive) but it doesn't print the colour code it should give of that coordinate. (254, 252, 0)

My theory is that it is taking the colours from the wrong thing, as in I don't think it is screenshotting my game, rather something else on screen, I think Visual Studio Code as it keeps returning grey colour codes which my game shouldn't be displaying.

I'm really stuck and any ideas would appreciated. :)

Comment: Interesting. Are you storing all the images? Does you program work with already stored images?

Comment: The first bit of code does save a screenshot but it doesn't even work with that, it doesn't actually 'store' them as such in the second piece of code. I think the issue is that it isn't getting the correct colour code on screen. It's very hard to explain sorry.

Comment: can you run the code with an already stored image? does that work? Additionally try to check following - 1. check whether your understanding of image data correct(example - coloured images could be sotred in form of 3D array each pixel having 3 RGB values)? 2. what kind of data the library function works on ?